# what is the output of with_contains and without_contains

Tags: python, scrapy, selector

what is the output of with_contains and without_contains and please explain contains, when I am not using contains then error is generate

> exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath: //div[@class, "product-name"]"

```
#<div class="product-name">Adcor Defense BEAR 223 16 OPT RDY</div>

with_contains = hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "product-name")]/text()').extract()
without_contains = hxs.select('//div[@class, "product-name"]/text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer on your question is quite simple - contains is string function, that check sub-string in value. For example:

```
..
<div class="product-name other_class">Example</div>
```

To get data from this element:

```
data = hxs.select('//div[contains(@class, "product-name")]/text()').extract()
```

If you don't use contains that means the class exactly equal provided value and you should use syntax @class="value , in your case:

```
exactly = hxs.select('//div[@class="product-name"]/text()').extract()
```

Comment: but when i am not use contains then why its getting error. => exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath: //div[@class, "product-name"]"

Comment: Because you use invalid syntax, you should use: ```//div[@class="product-name"]```

Comment: Hi, Alex did you mean is it incorrect => 
productname = hxs.select('//div[@class="product-name"]/text()').extract()